# What is the difference between `params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)` and ' params.require(:person).permit!'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know what is the difference between using

```
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit!
  end
```

and

```
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
  end
```

Comment: The first will permit all the attributes of the person while the second will permit only name and age.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[permit!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21)**

> Sets the permitted attribute to true

This allows anything that you send to it.

in the other had

**[permit(*filters)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)**

> Returns a new ActionController::Parameters instance that includes only the given filters and sets the permitted attribute for the object to true. This is useful for limiting which attributes should be allowed for mass updating.

so if you permit(:name, :age) and you pass in :gender it would not be permitted.